# How to copy all the Script names present in table into a array

Tags: jquery

From a Website i have copied a table by using view Source Option

From the table i am trying to copy all the script names into a array

For example the output i wanted is

```
[ADVANTA,AGRITECH,AVANTIFEED....]
```

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var scriptarray = [];

$('#mytable tr').each(function() {

    var tdscriptvalue =$(this).find("scrip").data;

   scriptarray.push(tdscriptvalue);

});

});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/8500/

Comment: What's the question? Is it working? If not, what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly,

You're pretty close there. You have an invalid selector for selecting `td`s

All the values from `ScripCode` column lie on the third column. This is a way how you can retrieve it.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var scriptarray = [];
  $('#mytable tr').each(function()
  {
    var tdscriptvalue = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text().trim();
    if (tdscriptvalue.length > 0)
      scriptarray.push(tdscriptvalue);
  });
  console.log(scriptarray);
});
```

Here's the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/8501/).

Comment: please don't use `&nbsp;` to left pad your content - use a `margin-left` style instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only supporting "good" browsers (MSIE 9+, or practically every version of every other browser) then you can directly access the third column of each row and gets its `textContent`:

```
var scriptarray = [].map.call($('#mytable tbody tr'), function(tr) {
    return tr.cells[2].textContent;
});
```

NB: this will include the additional space because of your `&nbsp` that you're using for padding.  You should use CSS to introduce that padding instead.